# How to get text value from td tag when using Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

The html looks like:

```
<tbody>
    <td>
      content
    </td>
</tbody>
```

I have located the element td by find_element_by_xpath function.However I only get string with no content even but in fact the web has content showed.

The code likes:
`driver.find_element_by_xpath('//tbody/td').text`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```py
.get_attribute('innerText')
```